# In Cov(X,Y), are X and Y both equal length vectors?

Tags: self-study

Backstory: I am very far in my Stats Major, but find that I have many holes in my understanding. I know this is ridiculous but I want to try my best to patch them up even though I really should know all of this already. Here goes.

$\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)$

What are the $X$ and $Y$? They are "random variables" I understand.

Random variable:a quantity having a numerical value for each member of a group, especially one whose values occur according to a frequency distribution.

I read this above definition and find I still have no idea what a random variable is. For example: each member of WHAT group?

So are X and Y both equally length vectors? In R, the following code returns an error:

```
    a <- 1:10
    b <- 5:6
    cov(a,b)
    Error in cov(a, b) : incompatible dimensions
```

This leads me to conclude that X and Y are not random variables, but are simply equal length vectors.

What is wrong with my understanding of random variables and the Cov() function?

If Cov() describes the relationship b/w two random variables, does R then treat random variables as vectors or vice versa?

Thank you so much and sorry for wasting the time of all the bright minds here on CrossValidated. Seriously.

Comment: 5:6 is a vector of "length" 2 and 1:10 is a vector of "length" 10, so they are not vectors of equal length. What would make you think they are?

Comment: Can anyone explain why this question was down-voted? It is an abuse that people who down-vote questions or answers do not get notifications when people comment. It enables then to continue to be cowards and bullies and prevents them from ever suspecting that they are not omniscient or infallible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Random variable:a quantity having a numerical value for each member of a group, especially one whose values occur according to a frequency distribution.

I'd rather say "set" than "group" because of the way in which the word "group" is used in algebra.

A typical example is the set of all outcomes of throwing two distinct dice:
$$
\begin{array}{cccccc}
(1,1) & (2,1) & (3,1) & (4,1) & (5,1) & (6,1) \\
(1,2) & (2,2) & (3,2) & (4,2) & (5,2) & (6,2) \\
(1,3) & (2,3) & (3,3) & (4,3) & (5,3) & (6,3) \\
(1,4) & (2,4) & (3,4) & (4,4)& (5,4) & (6,4) \\
(1,5) & (2,5) & (3,5) & (4,5) & (5,5) & (6,5) \\
(1,6) & (2,6) & (3,6) & (4,6) & (5,6) & (6,6)
\end{array}
$$
Assign each member of this set probability $1/36.$ Then we can define several random variables:
\begin{align}
U & = \text{the first of the two components -- the number shown on the first die} \\[6pt]
V & = \text{the second of the two components -- the number shown on the second die} \\[6pt]
W & = \max\{U,V\} = \text{whichever of those two is bigger} \\[6pt]
X & = U+V = \text{the sum of the two}
\end{align}
Any of these can be regarded as a vector of "length" $36$.

You gave this example:

```
    a <- 1:10
    b <- 5:6
    cov(a,b)
    Error in cov(a, b) : incompatible dimensions
```

Then you wrote "This leads me to conclude that X and Y are not random variables, but are simply equal length vectors." How you concluded that they are equal-length vectors is a mystery, since one of them has length $2$ and the other has length $10$, and it is precisely the difference in their lengths that caused the error message.

Sometimes the set whose every member is assigned a value is one in which every subset containing just one element is assigned probability zero, as with the normal distribution. But with the normal distribution, intervals are assigned positive probability. It is because of examples like that that one assigns probabilities not to members, but to subsets of the domain of the random variable.

When R returns a value in response to the command cov(x,y), where $x$ and $y$ are vectors of equal lengths, and the length is $n$, it assumes each point has probability $1/n$.

Comment: Michael you're right. That was poor wording! I meant to say that because Cov(a,b) returned an error, the X and Y of Cov(X,Y) are required only to be equal length vectors in order for R to return a non Error. X and Y do not necessarily have to be random variables for R to make some calculation. Rather, the must simply be equal length RVs. It seems however that such equal length vectors are mere instances or "draws" of a random variables.

Comment: @mach consider `cov(cbind(x,y),cbind(x,y))[1:nx,(nx+1):(nx+ny)]` as already discussed (in words) in my answer

Answer (score 3):

Grew too long for a comment... I guess it's an answer

In the expression $\text{Cov}(X,Y)$, $X$ and $Y$ are normally intended to be random variables (which might be univariate or they might be vector-valued).

If the random variables, are vector-valued then they don't need to be the same dimension. However, $\text{Cov}(x,y)$ could mean a *sample* covariance; that would require $n$ pairs of observations on $x$ and $y$ (whether they're vectors on each individual observation or or single numbers).

[In relation to a command in a package, like `cov(x,y)` in R, the requirements depend on the package and are usually explained in the help. In this case if you supply both `x` and `y` to `cov`, the R command expects vectors of observations (each individual having a single value on each, each representing a scalar random variable). This is clearly stated in the help.]

Incidentally, if you want the sample covariance between vector valued random variables, put their observations together into a matrix $M=(X,Y)$, and then supply *that* to a covariance-calculating routine; the matrix  $\text{Cov}(x,y)$ can be extracted as a submatrix from the resulting variance-covariance matrix of $M$.

Answer (score 0):

Covariance is a quantification of how linearly related $X$ is to the corresponding value of $Y$. That is, you need the data to be paired 1-to-1 to calculate covariance.

So, yes, you the vectors do need to be of equal length.

I don't understand why one would calculate the covariance between two non-random vectors so, also, yes--the inputs need to be random vectors.